# How I can get an array with 2 items from a selected item in a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, arraylist, jcombobox

I have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> Suppliers`. Each `ArrayList<Object>` has 2 elements, an int (an id and the id may not be sequential with each other.) and a string (a name). 
Now in a JComboBox, I create a DefaultComboBoxModel, containing the main ArrayList 'Suppliers'.

```
jcbSuppliers.setModel (new DefaultComboBoxModel (suppliersdata.Suppliers.toArray ()));
```

The JComboBox shows me each element such as [1, Local Supplier], [2, External Supplier], [4, Other Supplier].

[Capture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYE45.jpg)

In NetBeans debug, i put a Watch on jcbSuppliers. The variables window shows me that each element of jcbSuppliers is an ArrayList with 2 Objects.

[Capture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXs8J.jpg)

Now my question is:

How I can get these 2 items or the array of these 2 objects, but of the selected object or item?

I would appreciate the help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try using spring to be able to switch implementations through a xml config. Basically its common to create custom implementations of basic classes like myCustomComboBox where you override all processing and gui.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#configuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First I do have to give kudos to Flextra and his comment as Spring can help you decouple your code, making it much easier to enhance and debug.
- Next I suggest that you re-think your current model set up. Rather than begin with nested ArrayLists, I suggest that you create a custom class to hold the two pieces of data each supplier will need.
- Then create a *non-nested* ArrayList of this custom class.
- Then you can tell the JComboBox how to display an object of your either by giving it a `toString()` method that displays the information as you'd like it,
- or give the JComboBox a custom cell renderer that displays the information as you'd like it.
- Then when the combo box is selected, if you get the selectedItem, it will be an object of your class, and it will be easy to extract the two pertinent pieces of information.

Comment: +1 [Combo Box With Hidden Data](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) gives an example of the `toString()` approach and [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) gives an example of the `renderer` approach.

Comment: Excellent, it's just what I wanted to do. Many thanks to all for the help.

Comment: @user1953373: glad you've got things going.